# How to decode "state" request parameter sent by AWS Cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authorization, amazon-cognito

A couple of months ago, I had been using the `state` request parameter that AWS Cognito sent when requesting `/authorize` of my authorization server. I had used it for sending extra information from AWS Cognito to my authorization server. At the time the value was `base64`. Today I was trying the same thing, but I received a value that is not base64 for the state.
Have AWS changed the Cognito or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigation, I figured out that Cognito sends state in the `STRING1.STRING2.STRING3` format. `String1` is encoded with `base64url`. After decoding `STRING1` from `base64url`, it turned out that it is a `gzip` binary. Unzipping that results in state.

Previously, Cognito encode the state twice with `base64` encoding. Apparently, they changed the logic. I have not found any documentation that state this situation.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that when I use the `customState` parameter for Cognito's federated auth I get a state parameter back in the callback that is not gzip or base64 encoded. It's actually composed of two different strings with a dash, like:

`[AWS-specific string]-[hex encoded customState]`

The AWS-specific string has unknown (to me) encoding and content (maybe just a uid), but the customState is a hex-encoded string. For example, a customState string of "hi" will have an encoded string value of "6869".

I was able to successfully pass and decode JSON strings using this method.