Cannot decode cognito state string
I am calling cognito with a &state=xxxxxx parameter. when I get my redirection back, I see a state param in addition to the code. It seems to be encoded somehow, but not base64 nor gzip cannot decode it.
Does anyone know what the format of the state param returned by Cognito after successful login, and how to decode it?

Is this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72371122/how-to-decode-state-request-parameter-sent-by-aws-cognito ?
